# Rules of implicit numeric type conversions

Tags: c++

I have couple of questions about type conversions with signed and unsigned variables.
Which type will be chosen in case like this
`signed int + unsigned int  =  ???`

And what about cases when instead of variables i have constants

---

```
x1(unsigned int) = x1(unsigned int) - 0xFFFFFFFA
```

I have read something like constants will be `unsigned ints` unless it is explicitly written like `0xFFFFFFFA(UL)`.Then

```
1) unsigned int - unsigned int = unsigned int
2) unsigned int = unsigned int
```

And what if number with floating point

```
 x1(unsigned int) = x2(signed short int) + x3(unsigned int) + x4(unsigned short int) 
 * 0.1(float);  
 1)float * unsigned short int = float
 2)float + unsigned int = float 
 3)float + signed short int = float
 4)unsigned int = (unsigned int)float
```

---

Here i guess 'a' will be char

```
signed int = 'a' + signed short int - signed int 
1) 'a' + signed short int = int ???
2) int - signed int = int ???
3) signed int = (signed int) int ???
```

---

And one more

```
long double = signed int + wchar_t - unsigned int * 10 
1)unsigned int * 10(int) = int
2)wchar_t - int = int
3)signed int + int = int 
4)long double = (long double) int
```

Comment: The nice things about C++ is that you can figure this out all by yourself, without waiting for anyone to answer you on stackoverflow.com. Just assign the results to an `auto`, then take its `&` (address), and try to assign it to, for example, an `unsigned *`. If this compiles, then you know what is the type of the operation. If not, try again, until you get it right.

Comment: Better yet, just do `struct {} _ = some_expression;` and the compiler error message will tell you the exact type of `some_expression`. YouCompleteMe has `GetType`. CLion shows them on hover (I think)

Comment: I changed the title and opening sentence to refer to **conversions** instead of **casts**. A cast is something you write in your code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. There is no such thing as an implicit cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the trick I commented:

```
struct {} _ = some_expression;
```

The compiler error will tell you the exact type of the expression.

For backgrounders, see http://cppreference.com, specifically [Implicit Conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)

- [Numeric Promotions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Numeric_promotions)
- [Numeric Conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Numeric_conversions)

You should also read [conv.prom](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom) and [conv.double](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.double) in the standard.

Comment: I added the standard links to your answer and deleted my comment.  That way it is more self-contained.